# How to I install Bastion in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I downloaded Bastion quite a while ago from the Humble Indie Bundle. I still have the .deb file and would like to install it in Ubuntu 15.04.

Unfortunately, the installation fails:

```
[me@ubuntu debs]$ sudo dpkg -i bastion_1.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for gijs: 
Voorheen niet geselecteerd pakket bastion wordt geselecteerd.
(Database wordt ingelezen ... 355281 bestanden en mappen momenteel geïnstalleerd.)
Uitpakken van bastion_1.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb wordt voorbereid...
Uitpakken van bastion (1.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van bastion:
 bastion is afhankelijk van libalut0; maar:
  Pakket libalut0:amd64 is niet geïnstalleerd.
 bastion is afhankelijk van libsmpeg0; maar:
  Pakket libsmpeg0:amd64 is niet geïnstalleerd.
 bastion is afhankelijk van libsdl-gfx1.2-4; maar:
  Pakket libsdl-gfx1.2-4 is niet geïnstalleerd.

dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket bastion (--install):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
 bastion

[me@ubuntu debs]$ sudo apt-get install -f
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
Vereisten worden gecorrigeerd... Klaar
De volgende pakketten zijn automatisch geïnstalleerd en zijn niet langer nodig:
  libalut0 libsmpeg0
Gebruik 'apt-get autoremove' om ze te verwijderen.
De volgende extra pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
  libalut0 libsmpeg0
De volgende pakketten zullen VERWIJDERD worden:
  bastion
De volgende NIEUWE pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
  libalut0 libsmpeg0
0 opgewaardeerd, 2 nieuw geïnstalleerd, 1 te verwijderen en 9 niet opgewaardeerd.
1 niet volledig geïnstalleerd of verwijderd.
Er moeten 0 B/103 kB aan archieven opgehaald worden.
Na deze bewerking zal er 1259 MB schijfruimte vrijkomen.
Wilt u doorgaan? [J/n] 
(Database wordt ingelezen ... 356412 bestanden en mappen momenteel geïnstalleerd.)
bastion (1.4-0ubuntu1) wordt verwijderd ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Voorheen niet geselecteerd pakket libalut0:amd64 wordt geselecteerd.
(Database wordt ingelezen ... 355281 bestanden en mappen momenteel geïnstalleerd.)
Uitpakken van .../libalut0_1.1.0-5_amd64.deb wordt voorbereid...
Uitpakken van libalut0:amd64 (1.1.0-5) ...
Voorheen niet geselecteerd pakket libsmpeg0:amd64 wordt geselecteerd.
Uitpakken van .../libsmpeg0_0.4.5+cvs20030824-7.1_amd64.deb wordt voorbereid...
Uitpakken van libsmpeg0:amd64 (0.4.5+cvs20030824-7.1) ...
Instellen van libalut0:amd64 (1.1.0-5) ...
Instellen van libsmpeg0:amd64 (0.4.5+cvs20030824-7.1) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...

[me@ubuntu debs]$ sudo dpkg -i bastion_1.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Voorheen niet geselecteerd pakket bastion wordt geselecteerd.
(Database wordt ingelezen ... 355294 bestanden en mappen momenteel geïnstalleerd.)
Uitpakken van bastion_1.4-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb wordt voorbereid...
Uitpakken van bastion (1.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: vereistenproblemen verhinderen de configuratie van bastion:
 bastion is afhankelijk van libsdl-gfx1.2-4; maar:
  Pakket libsdl-gfx1.2-4 is niet geïnstalleerd.

dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket bastion (--install):
 vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
 bastion
```

This is probably due to the missing package `libsdl-gfx1.2-4`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Found it: download the .deb file for `libsdl-gfx1.2-4` from [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/libsdl-gfx1.2-4).

Afterwards, try to install the Bastion .deb file again. This should work.

Comment: Also works for ubuntu16.04, thx!